# How to change an if statement depending of Informations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, random

Here is my problem: I have a if statement regrouping multiple conditions eg: if(stat1 & stat2 & stat3 & stat4).

in this condition, I want to compare 4 times 2 numbers.

If the number 1 is negative and the number 2 positive, I want the if statement to be if(num1 >= num2 & ....). If the number 1 is positive and the number 2 is negative, I want the if statement to be if(num1 <= num2 & ...). If the numbers are both positive but number 1 is smaller, I want it to be if(num1 >= num2 & ...)

And I think you get it.

the problem is that i can't just make multiple if statements for every possibilities, since there are something like 8 cases per conditions and 4 conditions. Is there anyway I can adapt my if statement to fit my needs in the script ? 
In my case, my number one would be the x angle of a gameobject, and number 2 the x angle I want to get. My gameobject is being rotated in update with Time.deltaTime, but since it goes realyl fast, I can't just do if(number1 != number2), cause it would just skip it until it lands on it, and since I have 4 times 2 numbers, all the 4 numbers would need to fall on the good value, so I want to use <= or >=, for these reasons. My angles should stay between the interval (number1, number2), thats why I can't allow it to do a full 360 degree rotation, and I need to detect as soon as it passes the value. And I already have some code that choses whether I have to do Time.deltaTime * 1 or Time.deltaTime * -1, and it is important to never get a rotation around 180 degree.[image]

Comment: just write nested if statements

Comment: *`If the number 1 is positive and the number 2 is negative, I want the if statement to be if(num1 <= num2 ...`* That will never be true. num1 is positive, which means it is garaunteed to be larger than num2, as num2 is negative.

Comment: This sounds like a potential architectural/design issue. Perhaps you could elaborate more about the goal you are trying to resolve with the multiple nested if statements.

Comment: @Draco18s When I will decrease number 1 in my code, it will eventually be smaller than number 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow rotating to face cursor needs to only do so while inside an angle made by two given directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841720/arrow-rotating-to-face-cursor-needs-to-only-do-so-while-inside-an-angle-made-by)

Comment: @Draco18s I have something similar but mine is more specific

Comment: @SamuelFyckes I'm pretty sure that one of the various "how can I restrict the angle" questions that already exists will work, I tried to pick the one that most closely matched your question, but there are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Abs function in the System.Math class. This function does return the distance between 0 and the number. That way it doesn't matter wich one is positive or negative

```
if (System.Math.Abs(num1) >= System.Math.Abs(num2))
    {
         // Its here for n1= -150 and n2 = 120
         // Also here for n1 = 150 and n2 = -120
         // Also here when n1 and n2 are the same
    }
else{
        // Its outside for n1 = -100 and n2 = 120
        // Also outside for n1 = 100 and n2 = 120
    }
```

Comment: I already thought about that, but if both numbers are positive. than number1 >= number2 wouldn't work for both number1 is greater than number2 or number2 is greater than number1

Comment: When both numbers are positive, it works for num1>num2. If you want to add num2> num1 in the same condition, it would be better to use num1==num2 or make it into another condition

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use nested if statements and try to reduce the number of combinations if possible.

I'm not sure if you really need to know if the number is negative or not maybe you could utilize math absolute value. Provide more context and put more efforts in the question in order for us to help you better.

**Edit:**
Then why don't you check the abs value of the first rotation and if it exceeds 180 degrees then do the second rotation?

Comment: I added more context and effort